# How to create GUI objects one by one with Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, time, tkinter

I like to create an object per second and make the show up one by one. However, the code below wait for 3 seconds and show them all at the same time.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
def create():
   for i in range(3):
      r4=Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1"+str(i), value=1)
      r4.pack( anchor = W )
      time.sleep(1)
root = Tk()
create()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: sleep doesn't work well with tkinter's mainloop. You should check out [after method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, as is, creates a one object per second as you desired it, but this objects need to be shown, and they're shown when code flow reaches the `mainloop`. Hence, for observer, it looks like there're no objects at all after one second.

Of course, you can use `sleep` and `update`, but beware - `sleep`ing leads to unresponsive window, so it's OK option (to be honest - not OK at all), if your application isn't drawn and you're outside of `mainloop`, but if it's not - prepare for a "frozen" window, because GUI can redraw himself only in `mainloop` (an event loop, you can reach it with `update` as well) and `sleep` blocks this behaviour.

But there's a good alternative, the [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method, take a look on it!

And there's a snippet, so you can see the difference:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
import time

def create_with_sleep():
    for _ in range(3):
        tk.Radiobutton(frame_for_sleep, text="Sleep Option").pack(anchor='w')
        time.sleep(int(time_entry.get()))
        root.update()

def create_with_after(times=3):
    if times != 0:
        tk.Radiobutton(frame_for_after, text="After Option").pack(anchor='w')
        times -= 1
        root.after(int(time_entry.get()) * 1000, lambda: create_with_after(times))

root = tk.Tk()

test_yard_frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame_for_sleep = tk.Frame(test_yard_frame)
frame_for_after = tk.Frame(test_yard_frame)
test_yard_frame.pack()
frame_for_sleep.pack(side='left')
frame_for_after.pack(side='left')

button_frame = tk.Frame(root)
button_for_sleep = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Create 3 radiobuttons with sleep+update', command=create_with_sleep)
button_for_after = tk.Button(button_frame, text='Create 3 radiobuttons with after', command=create_with_after)
button_frame.pack()
button_for_sleep.pack(side='left')
button_for_after.pack(side='left')

time_label = tk.Label(root, text='Time delay in seconds:')
time_label.pack(fill='x')
time_entry = tk.Entry(root)
time_entry.insert(0, 1)
time_entry.pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

With 1 seconds delay there's no much difference, but you can try to increase delay to understand why [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) option is [preferable in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887729/time-delay-tkinter).

Comment: Thank you! it's really better than use sleep

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` to call a refresh on your objects.

In use, you would have to add the line `root.update()` in your `for` loop.

Comment: Hi @TimoThund if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. **Of course, there is no obligation to do this.**