# Python change current tkinter text

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I am making a tkinter window to show me the weather currently. Every 5 minutes, it will get the new weather, and then replace the old text.

To put in the text, I am using a Tkinter Label.

```py
T = Label(root, bg="black", fg="white", height=2, width=30, text="Some Text")
```

However, I looked on the internet, and I found a delete function, but it does not work with labels.

How would I go about changing the label text?

I want to change the label while the program is still in mainloop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way :

```
T = Label(root, bg="black", fg="white", height=2, width=30, text="Some Text")
T.config(text='New text')
```

Comment: There's just one problem, how do I do that while the mainloop is still running?

Comment: @PokestarFan You can use the method `after`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887729/time-delay-tkinter